# How do I import my word embedding vectors as float32 from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types

I'm currently working on a project where I'm generating word embedding vectors for a list of all nouns in a given language. I thought that I would save some time by saving the vectors into a csv after running the vocab through my Word2Vec Models and just importing them using the pd read_csv method. However, no matter what I try pandas seems insistent on importing the vectors as strings instead of float32. I've tried the dtype = np.float32 argument and have also tried casting the column after importing the data as strings.

```
filepath = r"C:\Users\name\Word Embedding Plots\Spanish\full_list_Spanish.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0, dtype = {'labels':str,'vector':np.float32,'noun class':int,'cluster labels':int})

Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float32') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-00320472335a> in <module>
      1 filepath = r"C:\Users\name\Word Embedding Plots\Spanish\full_list_Spanish.csv"
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0, dtype = {'labels':str,'vector':np.float32,'noun class':int,'cluster labels':int})

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    466 
    467     with parser:
--> 468         return parser.read(nrows)
    469 
    470 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1055     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1056         nrows = validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1057         index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1058 
   1059         if index is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2059     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2060         try:
-> 2061             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2062         except StopIteration:
   2063             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[ 5.26622403e-03  2.76202578e-02 -2.03670934e-04 -1.64115373e-02\n  6.28665928e-03 -1.83933843e-02  3.29369050e-03 -2.29671989e-02\n  
2.07041409e-02  8.32622871e-04  2.75359303e-02 -5.80102392e-03\n -1.33564807e-02  
3.53069953e-03  1.09354407e-02 -3.09148571e-04\n -9.04788449e-03  5.07736802e-02 
-6.27910532e-03 -5.59426378e-04\n  1.61280446e-02  2.35912427e-02 -4.09195535e-02  
2.05074325e-02\n -5.79257030e-03  2.38035228e-02 -1.78857855e-02  1.71619467e-02\n 
-1.51733253e-02 (cont.)
```

The DF itself is supposed to look like this (give or take some weird rounding issues with the noun class and cluster labels columns):

```
             label                                             vector  \
0       1 Crónicas  [ 5.26622403e-03  2.76202578e-02 -2.03670934e-...   
1           1 Juan  [-4.13045213e-02 -3.40997241e-04  6.59986138e-...   
2          1 Pedro  [ 1.93648413e-03  7.61903543e-03  5.45683019e-...   
3          1 Reyes  [-0.01713392  0.01234968 -0.00780387  0.013362...   
4         1 Samuel  [-1.28333392e-02  1.66266896e-02  3.92513275e-...   
...            ...                                                ...   
27321  zurracapote  [ 0.00381346 -0.03389708  0.01719903 -0.041144...   
27322   zurribanda  [ 5.69391288e-02 -2.35609561e-02  1.59582384e-...   
27323      zurrona  [ 1.41258361e-02 -2.26027071e-02  3.31467316e-...   
27324       zutana  [-1.86217669e-02 -7.71664307e-02  4.62110750e-...   
27325   zwingliana  [-1.19532188e-02 -2.14482211e-02  9.92432088e-...   

       noun class  cluster labels  
0          0.0000          3.0000  
1          0.0000          3.0000  
2          0.0000          3.0000  
3          0.0000          3.0000  
4          0.0000          3.0000  
...           ...             ...  
27321      1.0000          2.0000  
27322      1.0000          2.0000  
27323      1.0000          2.0000  
27324      1.0000          0.0000  
27325      1.0000          2.0000  

[60934 rows x 4 columns]
```

Is it possible to import the vectors as float32 arrays?

Comment: your vector is NOT `np.float32` but `list of float values` - or rather `numpy.array with float values` - so using `'vector':np.float32` is totally wrong. You should first load it as string and later use some code to convert `string` into list with float values.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem.  Show the code that writes the vectors so we can suggest the whole solution to write and retrieve the values.

Comment: better you should write in csv as normal list and then you could use `json.loads` to convert string back to list with values.

Comment: you may also try to use `np.fromstring()` but it may need to remove `[ ]` - `np.fromstring('5.26622403e-03 2.76202578e-02', sep=' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `float` in `vector` but `string with list` (or rather with `numpy.array`) and you can't convert it using `dtype=np.float32` because it expects string with single value.

You would have to read it as string and later use `apply()` to run some function which will convert string to list with values.

And you have to remeber that you will get `list with floats`, not single `float` so `dtype` will not be `float` but `object.

---

Miniaml working example.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory.

```
text = '''label,vector
1 Crónicas,[ 5.26622403e-03  2.76202578e-02 ]   
1 Juan,[-4.13045213e-02 -3.40997241e-04 ]
1 Pedro,[ 1.93648413e-03  7.61903543e-03 ]
1 Reyes,[-0.01713392  0.01234968 ]
1 Samuel,[-1.28333392e-02  1.66266896e-02 ]
zurracapote,[ 0.00381346 -0.03389708 ]
zurribanda,[ 5.69391288e-02 -2.35609561e-02 ]
zurrona,[ 1.41258361e-02 -2.26027071e-02 ]
zutana,[-1.86217669e-02 -7.71664307e-02 ]
zwingliana,[-1.19532188e-02 -2.14482211e-02 ]'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))

def convert(item):
    item = item.strip()  # remove spaces at the end
    item = item[1:-1]    # remove `[ ]`
    item = np.fromstring(item, sep=' ')  # convert string to `numpy.array`
    return item

df['vector'] = df['vector'].apply(convert)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also use this function directly in `read_csv(..., converters=...)`

```
text = '''label,vector
1 Crónicas,[ 5.26622403e-03  2.76202578e-02 ]   
1 Juan,[-4.13045213e-02 -3.40997241e-04 ]
1 Pedro,[ 1.93648413e-03  7.61903543e-03 ]
1 Reyes,[-0.01713392  0.01234968 ]
1 Samuel,[-1.28333392e-02  1.66266896e-02 ]
zurracapote,[ 0.00381346 -0.03389708 ]
zurribanda,[ 5.69391288e-02 -2.35609561e-02 ]
zurrona,[ 1.41258361e-02 -2.26027071e-02 ]
zutana,[-1.86217669e-02 -7.71664307e-02 ]
zwingliana,[-1.19532188e-02 -2.14482211e-02 ]'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

def convert(item):
    item = item.strip()  # remove spaces at the end
    item = item[1:-1]    # remove `[ ]`
    item = np.fromstring(item, sep=' ')  # convert string to list
    return item

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), converters={'vector':convert})

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```